# insert data into mysql many to many relation via php

Tags: php, mysql

I have three tables-
Class (parent table)
Announcement (child table)
Class-ann(junction table)

All have their respective autoincrement ids
I am.looking to insert a new announcement into announcement table and assign it to a class in class-ann table
Please help me in that.
I can easily retrieve table using join. Should i use a join and then insert? Also classID will be predefined

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any reason to use a join unless you're going to be using that data somewhere else. Just do an insert into the Class-ann table using the class_id and announcement_id from your other tables.

Comment: Thanks. But announcement needs to be insertwd in table announcement andassigned to a class id at the same time